# Как сделать 3 кнопки которые меняют друг друга? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть 3 кнопки, 2 из которых скрыты. При нажатии на кнопку, первая кнопка скрывается, появляется вторая. При нажатии на вторую, появляется третья, вторая скрывается. При нажатии на третью удаляется определённый элемент.
При помощи `ng-switch` пробовал, но что-то не так.

```
<td ng-switch="flag">
    <button type="button" ng-swith-when="flag=0" ng-click="flag=1" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
    <button type="button" ng-switch-when="flag=1" ng-click="flag=2" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    <button type="button" ng-switch-when="flag=2" ng-click="" class="btn btn-danger">Complete</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Покажите код, которым пытались реализовать.

Comment: Если я правильно помню как работает `ng-switch` то нужно писать так: `ng-switch-when="1"`. И, кстати, в первом `ng-swith-when` пропущена буква `c`